# conditional dataframe operations using Pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, conditional-statements, dataframe

I am doing some calculations on a dataFrame `A`: I want to add a new column `RESULT`, and do the following calculation:

There usually are multiple rows with the same `key1` values and their `key2`  can be either `X` or `Y`. For each group having the same `key1`:
If `key2 = X`, then `RESULT = 0`,
else, `RESULT = (C1 | key2= Y)+ (C2| key2= Y)+ (C2| key2= X)`. See `A_MODIFIED`.

```
    A =
        key1   key2  C1    C2    
    0   A      X     5     2     
    1   A      Y     3     2     
    2   B      X     6     1     
    3   B      Y     1     3     
    4   C      Y     1     4     
    5   D      X     2     3     
    6   D      Y     1     3     

   A_MODIFIED =
       key1   key2  C1    C2    RESULT
   0   A      X     5     2     0
   1   A      Y     3     2     7
   2   B      X     6     1     0
   3   B      Y     1     3     5
   4   C      Y     1     4     5
   5   D      X     2     3     0
   6   D      Y     1     3     7
```

This is what I did:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(A.groupby('key1', sort = False).sum().ix[:, ['C2']].sum(axis=1), columns=['C2_T']).reset_index(level=1)
df2 = A[A['key2'] == 'Y']
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'left').set_index(df1.index)
df3.RESULT = df3.C1+ df3.C2_T
```

But now I don't know how to merge it with the original `A`.

Comment: I don't think your formula makes sense.  `RESULT = 0` when `key2 = X`, but then you have `... + (C2 | key2 = X)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply function `f` for each group.

Function `f` sum all values of column `C2`, because there not depends on value of `key2`. Values of `C1` depends on `key2`, so there are selected only value with `df['key2'] == 'Y'`.

Last if `df['key2'] == 'X'` output is set to `0`.

```
print A
#  key1 key2  C1  C2
#0    A    X   5   2
#1    A    Y   3   2
#2    B    X   6   1
#3    B    Y   1   3
#4    C    Y   1   4
#5    D    X   2   3
#6    D    Y   1   3

def f(df):
    df['RESULT'] = df['C2'].sum() + df['C1'].loc[df['key2'] == 'Y'].sum()
    df['RESULT'].loc[df['key2'] == 'X'] = 0
    return df

df = A.groupby('key1', sort = False).apply(f)
print df
#  key1 key2  C1  C2  RESULT
#0    A    X   5   2       0
#1    A    Y   3   2       7
#2    B    X   6   1       0
#3    B    Y   1   3       5
#4    C    Y   1   4       5
#5    D    X   2   3       0
#6    D    Y   1   3       7
```